# TTF Font with Java AWT Graphics

Tags: java, graphics, fonts, awt, truetype

Using AWT graphics, I am attempting to draw text with a .ttf font.  But when drawn on the screen it only displays text in what looks to be font size 1.

Font initialization code:

```
font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new FileInputStream("font.ttf"));
font.deriveFont(24F);
fontSmall = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new FileInputStream("font.ttf"));
fontSmall.deriveFont(16F);
```

And yes, those statements are inside of a try statement.

And the code that is supposed to correctly draw text with the font:

```
g.setFont(font);
g.setColor(RED);
g.drawString("Test123",10,10);
g.setFont(fontSmall);
g.drawString("Test123SMALL",10,10);
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try with:

```
font = font.deriveFont(24F);
```

And:

```
fontSmall = fontSmall.deriveFont(16F);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
font = font.deriveFont(24F);
```

This should work, but when you try:

```
font = font.deriveFont(24);
```

The font looks to be size 1.